# Have a few doubts in this code...(pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

this is the code which is working fine...

```
int main()
{
    char c[]={'\t','\n','\0'};
    int i;
    char *p,*str;
    str=c;
    p=&c[1];
    printf("%d\n%d\n",*p,*str);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is why is it `str=c;` and  not `str=&c;`(which gives errors) and its `p=&c[1];`
and not `p=c[1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used in an expressions, references to objects of type `array-of-T` (i.e. array names) decay into pointers to their first element. <sup>[1]</sup> The resulting type of such pointers is `pointer-to-T`.

Also when you access to an array element by index, it gets dereferenced. That's why you use `&` to get its address.

To wrap it up, in the expressions you posted

- `c` equates to `&c[0]`
- `c[1]` is the value in second position in the array. `&c[1]` is its memory address, i.e. a pointer to it.

---

<sub>[1] There are four notable exceptions to this fact: when the array is the operand of a `sizeof`, `&` or - since [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) - `_Alignof` operator, or when it is a string literal initializer for a character array. Reference: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html.</sub>

Comment: No, the array name it is not a pointer. It is _converted_ to a pointer, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or address (`&`) operator, or a string literal used to initialise an array.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think it's a subtle difference in this case, but I'll edit my answer

Comment: Let's be nitpicky. Edited again.

Comment: Nitpicky it is... They're not "converted". An array's name is the address of the first element. :)

Comment: Got it. Thnx a lot Gabriele and team :D

Comment: You're welcome. I learned something too, answering to the question :)

Answer (score 4):

When you make an assignment, both sides of the assignment need to be *type compatible*.

In certain scenarios name of an array decays as an pointer to its first element. So `c` returns pointer to a char, i.e `char *` while `&c` gives address of an array, which is clearly not of the type `char *`(*type of `str` is `char*`*), the type mismatch gives you a diagnostic in the form of compilation error.

`&c[1]` gives you a `char *` while `c[1]` gives the value at that index, i.e: `char`. In this case *type* of `p` is again `char *` and hence the observed result.

---

**Good Read:**
[How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: It is not just the name of an array that is converted to a pointer to its first element. **Any** array expression is converted to a pointer to its first element (except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, `&`, or `_Alignof` or is a string literal initializing an array). So, if `x` is declared as `int x[3][4][5]`, then `*(x[2]+1)` is converted to a pointer to `int`, because it is a pointer to an array of five `int`. (The result of the conversion is the same as `&x[2][1][0]`.)